# Separating column into single column and formating the entries

Tags: r, split, datatable, formatting

I have a huge data table with two columns (`id` and `info`) and I want to separate/split the column `info` into single columns and format them.
Here is an example, how my data table's entries look like:

```
id <- c(8750, 3048, 3593, 8475, 9921)
info <- c("[J/B][10,00/10,00][1,500/1,500][1,00]", "[J*/POP][0,00/0,00/0,00/0,00][2,210/2,210/2,210/2,210][1,50]", "S", "KEINE",
          "[Q*/B][5,00/5,00][1,500/1,500][0,70]")
dt.test <- data.table(id, info)
dt.test
#   id                                                         info
# 8750                        [J/B][10,00/10,00][1,500/1,500][1,00]
# 3048 [J*/POP][0,00/0,00/0,00/0,00][2,210/2,210/2,210/2,210][1,50]
# 3593                                                            S
# 8475                                                        KEINE
# 9921                         [Q*/B][5,00/5,00][1,500/1,500][0,70]
```

At the end I need a table, where the `info` column is separated into six single columns (`id`, `type`, `pBu`, `pBo`, `zTBu`, `zTBo` and  `zV`) and formatting them as follows:

```
#   id   type pBu pBo zTBu zTBo  zV
# 8750    J/B  10  10 1.50 1.50 1.0
# 3048 J*/POP   0   0 2.21 2.21 1.5
# 3593      S  NA  NA   NA   NA  NA
# 8475  KEINE  NA  NA   NA   NA  NA
# 9921   Q*/B   5   5 1.50 1.50 0.7
```

Just a little explanation of my `info` column at the beginning and how the end data table should look:

- ALL commas `,` in the `info` column have to be replaced by an dot `.` (see my end data table).
- The inputs of the first brackets `[]` are defining my new `type` column, and furthermore, if the `info` column is filled with "S" or "KEINE", this also has to be an entry of `type` column.
- The inputs of the second brackets `[]` are defining the new columns `pBu` (first element) and `pBo` (last element).
- The inputs of the third brackets `[]` are defining new columns `zTBu` (first element) and `zTBo` (last element).
- The input of the fourth brackets `[]` is defining the `zV` column.
- When `type` column has entry "S" or "KEINE", then the remaining columns have to be filled with `NA`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code could combine the built-in function `gsub` and the function `tstrsplit` from `data.table`. If you want to set missing values to 0 as you asked in the comment [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646868/separating-column-into-single-column-and-formating-the-entries#comment121320289_68647542), you could just set the argument `fill` in the function `tstrsplit` to 0. Given that you retain that your data.table is huge, note that this answer is significantly faster than the one proposed by @dy_by (about 23 times faster on my machine).

This solution requires R version 4.1.0

```
cols <- c("type", "pBu", "pBo", "zTBu", "zTBo", "zV")

dt.test[, (cols) := gsub(",", ".", info, fixed=TRUE) |>
                    gsub(pattern="^\\[|\\]$", replacement="") |> 
                    gsub(pattern="/[0-9./]+/", replacement="/") |> 
                    tstrsplit("\\]\\[|/(?=\\d)", perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)]


dt.test[, !"info"]
#       id   type   pBu   pBo  zTBu  zTBo    zV
# 1:  8750    J/B    10    10  1.50  1.50   1.0
# 2:  3048 J*/POP     0     0  2.21  2.21   1.5
# 3:  3593      S    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 4:  8475  KEINE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 5:  9921   Q*/B     5     5  1.50  1.50   0.7
```

## Update

This is an update to take into the comment. It is meant to be used in R version older than 4.1.0

```
dt.test[, (cols) := {x <- gsub(",", ".", info, fixed=TRUE)
                     x <- gsub("^\\[|\\]$", "", x)
                     x <- gsub("/[0-9./]+/", "/", x)
                     tstrsplit(x, "\\]\\[|/(?=\\d)", perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)}]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. In each line the ``|>`` is underlined red and throws an error...

Comment: That is because your R is not updated. the native pipe, `|>`, requires R version 4.1.0, which is the current version of R. This solution would not work on an older version except if you update your R or adapt the solution to an older version. Two ways to adapt it to an older version: 1-replace `|>` with `%>%` from the package `magrittr` or 2-See updated solution. Check out the value of the following built-in variable to know the version of R you are using: `R.version.string`. If you choose to update your R, it would be better to also update R studio so that so it will account for this change

Comment: Let me know the version of R you are using. Also, test the new code and let me know if it works

Comment: Your update works fine for me. My R-version is 3.6.3

Comment: Ok for my large data table, you version doesn't work. The Error is: ``Error in `[.data.table`(dt.san2020, , `:=`((cols), { : 
  Supplied 5 items to be assigned to 470 items of column 'type'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.``

Comment: Have you made any modifications to the code (like adapting it or writing it differently for example) before using it? If so tell me exactly what you changed or modified; or copy and paste the piece of code you are using in the comment so that I can check what the issue is.

Comment: No I have just copied you updated version.

Comment: Run this piece of code and let me know the result: `dt.test[, {x <- gsub(",", ".", info, fixed=TRUE); x <- gsub("^\\[|\\]$", "", x); x <- gsub("/[0-9./]+/", "/", x);length(tstrsplit(x, "\\]\\[|/(?=\\d)", perl=TRUE))}]`

Comment: No unfortunately not. Using this only gives me the number ``6`` in my ``R`` console.

Comment: Today your update of your answer (for older ``R`` version) works. Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

1. `separate` on *brackets*
2. take first and last part of it (`mutate` and `word`)
3. sub `,` to `.` (`map_df`)
4. clean up left bracket (second `map_df`)
5. `select` to keep proper order of the
   columns

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
dt.test %>% 
  separate(info, into = c('type', 'pBu - pBo', 'zTBu - zTBo',  'zV'), 
           sep = "\\]|\\/ " , 
           remove = T) %>% 
  mutate('pBu' = word(`pBu - pBo`,1, sep = "\\/"),
         'pBo' = word(`pBu - pBo`,-1, sep = "\\/"),
         'pBu - pBo' = NULL,
         
         'zTBu' = word(`zTBu - zTBo`,1, sep = "\\/"),
         'zTBo' = word(`zTBu - zTBo`,-1, sep = "\\/"),
         'zTBu - zTBo' = NULL) %>% 
  map_df(~ gsub(",", ".", .x)) %>%
  map_df(~ gsub("\\[", "", .x)) %>% 
  select(id ,  type, pBu, pBo, zTBu, zTBo,  zV) ## %>% as.data.table


output
# A tibble: 5 x 7
  id    type   pBu   pBo   zTBu  zTBo  zV   
  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 8750  J/B    10.00 10.00 1.500 1.500 1.00 
2 3048  J*/POP 0.00  0.00  2.210 2.210 1.50 
3 3593  S      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
4 8475  KEINE  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
5 9921  Q*/B   5.00  5.00  1.500 1.500 0.70
```

`%>% as.data.table` at the end, allow you keep data.table form

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code works for me, but it also throws two warnings: 
``1: Expected 4 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 3 rows [1, 2, 5]. ``
``2: Expected 4 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [3, 4]. ``

Comment: dont worry bout this. that's a proper behavior. First: `discarded` couse thrown out part after last `]` - in your case its just discarding nothing, until there is nothing after the last right bracket. Second: in 3rd and 4th row is only one value (S, KEINE); function expect 4 values, so they are `filled ` by `NA`s

Comment: Alright! The second warning is ok because I want these ``NA``s. What if I want to replace the ``NA``s by ``0``s???

Comment: just add ```%>% replace_na(list(type = 0, `pBu - pBo` = 0,  `zTBu - zTBo` = 0, zV = 0))```after `separate` or `%>% replace_na(list(type = 0, pBu = 0,  pBo = 0,  zTBu = 0, zTBo = 0, zV = 0))` after mutate